# Find sibling node by xpath with Python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

Here is a fragment of xml. I need to use selenium to find the quote id value **1616968600**, but I'm new to xpath and I could use some help.

```
<div class="row">
    .....
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 ng-scope" style="font-weight: bold" translate="Business_Partner_Id">Business partner name: </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 ng-binding">Avnet Hall-Mark</div>
    <div class="col-md-2 ng-scope" style="font-weight: bold" translate="Quote_Id">Quote ID: </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 ng-binding">1616968600</div>               
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Locate the `div` having `Quote ID` text and get the [next sibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/following-sibling):

```
//div[contains(., "Quote ID")]/following-sibling::div
```

Usage:

```
quote_id_elm = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[contains(., "Quote ID")]/following-sibling::div')
print(quote_id_elm.text)
```